# Store and Retrieve Files with Amazon S3 using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I configured `AWSServiceManager` like below

```
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "us-east-1:ccd38470-cc11-4d1d-9437-83a6491af009")
let defaultServiceConfirguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfirguration
```

I am following [AWSS3TransferManager guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html) to store a file into S3 using iOS SDK installed by Pod. But I am getting an error like below,

> Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={HostId=zT0n9AYnVcKe0w9oXuahIB4DNyNoy9ABFzk5MFNVCs8/RJbQpiq52Ejp0X2BfA+w6BnpPZxSkE=,
>   Bucket=mybucket, Endpoint=s3TestApp.s3.amazonaws.com, Message=The
>   bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the
>   specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.,
>   Code=PermanentRedirect, RequestId=95F73C956B7FB36

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221439/ios-aws-v2-s3-transfer-manager-must-use-specified-endpoint) I found they are using something like `[downloadRequest setEndpoint:@"s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.com"];` to a `S3GetObjectRequest` object.

But here first of all here I am trying to upload the file and also using Swift not Objective-C. 
I would like to inform that there are there more bucket inside my root bucket where I am trying to upload.

Can anybody please help me to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The method you mentioned is from the version 1 of the SDK and is not applicable to the version 2 of the SDK.

You need to set the correct region to `AWSServiceConfiguration` object. See [this sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/S3TransferManager-Sample/Swift/S3TransferManagerSampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L25) for more details.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I already configured the `AWSServiceManager` the way you suggested. I got the error on `EndPoint`

Comment: Your bucket `s3TestApp` is not in `.USEast1`. You need to configure the service configuration object properly.

Comment: No it's in `USEast1` region.