# S3: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

Wants to upload an image to `S3`, but get this error:

> Image upload faulted: true filename: 10211282278486891.photo error:
>   Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={RequestId=6392E3155D770AF8, Bucket=something,
>   HostId=Lc1RcDdY+lqdquZLWtd/+k5eexkpLtTWwSmsi3ZWDp/QFP2jNu+duXcOcX25IOkCR5t6ZzkIoIE=,
>   Message=The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed
>   using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this
>   endpoint., Code=PermanentRedirect,
>   Endpoint=something.s3.amazonaws.com})

What Is wrong?

```
let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
uploadRequest.bucket = "something"
uploadRequest.key = filename
uploadRequest.body = url

transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith(block: {task in

    print("Image upload faulted: \(task.isFaulted) filename: \(filename) error: \(task.error)")
    return nil
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS AWS v2 S3 Transfer Manager must use specified endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221439/ios-aws-v2-s3-transfer-manager-must-use-specified-endpoint)